# AutoMapper PreCondition that checks destination

Tags: c#, automapper

Steps:

1. Receive ViewModel to update or create entity
2. Attempt to get existing entity if it exists
3. Call `IMapper.map(viewModel, entity)`

Because I'm providing a destination value to the map, is it possible to check that destination value for PreConditions?

Something like

```
.ForMember(x => x.Id, opt => {
   opt.PreCondition((src, desintation) => destination.Id == null);
   opt.MapFrom(src => Guid.NewGuid());
}
```

Is that possible? Maybe there's a better approach?

Comment: What's the precondition supposed to do here? Only map if something is null? Or something else?

Comment: only map if the destination doesn't have an Id

Comment: Preconditions [can only look at the source object](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Conditional-mapping.html#preconditions) - which makes sense when you think that the destination object may not exist yet, even though in your case it does - but when you're defining the mapping, AutoMapper cannot know that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found it

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.EditedBy, opt => {
    opt.PreCondition((src, dest, context) => dest.Id != Guid.Empty);
    opt.MapFrom(src => Guid.NewGuid());
});
```